# Ensuring maximum required permissions during Android manifest merging for location/bluetooth permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a modular codebase. One of my modules needs to always request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Another module only needs to request this permission up to SDK level 30.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

If I build an app which includes *both* of those modules, I would expect the merged manifest to contain.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

However, it shows up with `maxSdkVersion="30"`. This seems like incorrect/unexpected merging behavior.

How can I fix this?

Background info: one module uses Bluetooth permissions simply to connect to Bluetooth devices; the other uses it to scan for Bluetooth beacons, [thus requiring `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` irregardless of SDK level.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions.
The permissions you ask for changed with Android OS 12, and the maxSdkVersion="30" option helps you differentiate between pre and post OS 12 options.